# Spatial correlation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I'm looking into performing a spatial correlation test of 2 matrices to see where they overlay. To do so I need to create a grid layer of 2.2km2 around the coordinate points. I've tried the vector - research tools -vector grid but the parameters are in XY, while the UTM locations set to WGS84 - UTM36N, same as the project projection. How can I create a grid layer of 2kmx2km for the extent of my trap layout layer?
Using QGis 2.8.

Comment: no idea how vector grid should work, but if you change project coordinate system to something that uses meters as units and after that create vector grid. I assume that wgs84 - utm36 uses degrees as units

Comment: try mmqgis you have contro about everything